# Original dict/json from a pd.io.json.json_normalize() dataframe row

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a pandas dataframe with rows created from dicts, using `pd.io.json.json_normalize()`. The values(not the keys/columns names) in dataframe have been modified. I want to retrieve a dict, with the same nested format the original dict has, from a row of the dataframe.

```
sample = {
    "A": {
        "a": 7        
    },

    "B": {
        "a": "name",
        "z":{
            "dD": 20 ,
            "f_f": 3 ,    
        }
    }
}

df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(sample, sep='__')
```

as expected `df.columns` returns me:

```
Index(['A__a', 'B__a', 'B__z__dD', 'B__z__f_f'], dtype='object')
```

I want to "reverse" the process now.

I can guarantee no string in the original dict(key or value) has a '__' as a substring and neither starts or ends with '_'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inverse of Pandas json\_normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776916/inverse-of-pandas-json-normalize)