# Transform Excel to nested JSON data

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dictionary

I have an application that receives a JSON in the following format:

```json
{
  "name": "person name",
  "food": {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "meal": {
      "lunch": "burger",
      "dinner": "pizza"
    }
  }
}
```

However I need to create an Excel (or csv) with that data, and transform that Excel into this format.

I tried to create an dictionary like this:

```
name,food.fruit,food.meal.lunch,food.meal.dinner
person name,apple,burger,pizza
```

I am trying to use pandas, but I am not being able to deal with this multi level headers to transform into a python dictionary.

## Options

- What is the best way to write this data into an CSV or Excel?
- How to use Pandas to split the headers and convert it into a multi-level nested JSON?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I have updated the question. I am sorry I was not clear, but I am confused if I should change the way the data is written on the CSV, or if Pandas is a good solution for my output...

Comment: I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776916/inverse-of-pandas-json-normalize) may be useful for you

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776916/inverse-of-pandas-json-normalize) it's almost all I need but apparently it does not consider arrays

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `json_normalize` as below:

```py
import pandas as pd

 jsn = {
  "name": "person name",
  "food": {
    "fruit": "apple",
    "meal": {
      "lunch": "burger",
      "dinner": "pizza"
    }
  }
}

# create the flat structure
df = pd.json_normalize(jsn,  errors='ignore')
# write to a csv file
df.to_csv('file_name.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: What if I want the opposite, it generates the same input JSON?
I have tried to run the generated csv.to_json() but it does not convert the keys to inside objects, which is what I need.