# subtraction from nested dictioanaries in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to find the difference in the unique_users and total_sessions for the latest day(2023-09-06) and previous day(2023-09-07) for a specific hour 2 and 13 separately for each key 'jio' and 'other' and for a specific Exception. I need to consider the Exception and Hour and Date to calculate the difference. At the end I want to get the top two `unique_users`

```
Date    Hour    Exception   cell
0   2023/09/06  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 39273, 'unique_users': 30837}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 9523, 'unique_users': 7690}}}
1   2023/09/06  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 46870, 'unique_users': 39330}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 11745, 'unique_users': 10059}}}
2   2023/09/07  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}}
3   2023/09/07  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}}
```

```
result_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(result_df['Date'])

# Filter for the latest day
latest_day = result_df[result_df['Date'] == result_df['Date'].max()]

# Filter for the previous day
previous_day = result_df[result_df['Date'] == (result_df['Date'].max() - pd.DateOffset(days=1))]

result = {}
for key in latest_day['cell'].values[0].keys():

    latest_unique_users = latest_day['cell'].values[0][key]['unique_users']
    previous_unique_users = previous_day['cell'].values[0][key]['unique_users']

    result[key] = {
        'unique_users_diff': latest_unique_users - previous_unique_users,
    }
```

But I would like to get the difference in the original dataframe itself. The previous date 2023-09-06 rows are not neeed in the final dataframe. My current code is not considering the specific hour and specific exception for the calculation.

Expected output:

```
Date    Hour    Exception   Cell    design_jio_total_sessions_diff  design_jio_unique_users_diff  design_nokia_total_sessions_diff   design_nokia_unique_users_diff
1   2023/09/07  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}}  -1469   -1183  -785  -418

2   2023/09/07  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}}  -11182  -9702  -2986  -2522
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this problem is very easy when you split/explode the dictionary data into different columns, `pd.json_normalize` ends up being fairly easy to use.
I've added a few temp variables so that it easy to follow but you can remove that in your impelementation:

```
import ast 
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['cell'].apply(ast.literal_eval)) # you might not need to do ast.liter_eval
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
df3 = df3.sort_values(['Hour', 'Exception', 'Date'], ascending=True)

# group by and calculate difference
diff = df3.groupby(['Hour', 'Exception'])[df2.columns].diff()

# clean and join
diff.columns = ["diff_"+ x for x in diff.columns]
df3 =pd.concat([df3, diff], axis=1)
df3.dropna().drop(columns=df2.columns)
```

Output:

| Date | Hour | Exception | cell | diff_design.jio.total_sessions | diff_design.jio.unique_users | diff_design.nokia.total_sessions | diff_design.nokia.unique_users | diff_design.jio.total_sessions | diff_design.jio.unique_users | diff_design.nokia.total_sessions | diff_design.nokia.unique_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-09-07 00:00:00 | 2 | S1AP | {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}} | -1469 | -1183 | -785 | -418 | -1469 | -1183 | -785 | -418 |
| 2023-09-07 00:00:00 | 13 | S1AP | {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}} | -11182 | -9702 | -2986 | -2522 | -11182 | -9702 | -2986 | -2522 |

Comment: Can we just add the dictionary form of the difference for the `cell` column in the dataframe, if I do not want  diff_design.jio.total_sessions and all other columns?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776916/inverse-of-pandas-json-normalize

Comment: I have created a separate post for this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77371015/return-a-difference-of-nested-dictionary-in-a-new-column-of-a-dataframe