# return a difference of nested dictionary in a new column of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where I want to find the difference in the unique_users and total_sessions for the latest day(2023-09-06) and previous day(2023-09-07) for a specific hour 2 and 13 separately for each key 'jio' and 'other' and for a specific Exception. I need to consider the Exception and Hour and Date to calculate the difference. Get the top two `'total_sessions'` and `unique_users`

```
Date    Hour    Exception   cell
0   2023/09/06  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 39273, 'unique_users': 30837}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 9523, 'unique_users': 7690}}}
1   2023/09/06  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 46870, 'unique_users': 39330}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 11745, 'unique_users': 10059}}}
2   2023/09/07  13  S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}}
3   2023/09/07  2   S1AP    {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}}
```

I want to write a `generic function` which can be applied to similar columns such as `cell`

What I have tried :

```
import ast 
df2 = pd.json_normalize(df['cell']
df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)
df3 = df3.sort_values(['Hour', 'Exception', 'Date'], ascending=True)

# group by and calculate difference
diff = df3.groupby(['Hour', 'Exception'])[df2.columns].diff()

# clean and join
diff.columns = ["diff_"+ x for x in diff.columns]
df3 =pd.concat([df3, diff], axis=1)
df3.dropna().drop(columns=df2.columns)
```

`Expected output`:

```
 Date   Hour    Exception   IMSI_Operator   
2023-09-07 00:00:00 2   S1AP: NAS: [2] Detach   {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': -1469, 'unique_users': -1183}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': -785, 'unique_users': -418}}}  
2023/09/07 0:00 13  S1AP: NAS: [2] Detach   {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 11182, 'unique_users': 9702}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 2986, 'unique_users': 2522}}}
```

Comment: When a list or dictionary is included in a data frame, it is easier to receive a response by providing input as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in your previous post, you can use the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54776916/inverse-of-pandas-json-normalize) to get your desired output:

```
def df_to_formatted_json(df, sep="."):
    """
    The opposite of json_normalize
    """
    result = []
    for idx, row in df.iterrows():
        parsed_row = {}
        for col_label,v in row.items():
            keys = col_label.split(sep)

            current = parsed_row
            for i, k in enumerate(keys):
                if i==len(keys)-1:
                    current[k] = v
                else:
                    if k not in current.keys():
                        current[k] = {}
                    current = current[k]
        # save
        result.append(parsed_row)
    return result

cols = [x for x in df3.columns if x.startswith('diff_design')]
df3['newcell'] = df_to_formatted_json(df3[cols])
df3.drop(columns=cols)
```

Output:

| Date | Hour | Exception | cell | newcell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07-09-2023 | 2 | S1AP | {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 37804, 'unique_users': 29654}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8738, 'unique_users': 7272}}} | {'diff_design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': -1469.0, 'unique_users': -1183.0}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': -785.0, 'unique_users': -418.0}}} |
| 07-09-2023 | 13 | S1AP | {'design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': 35688, 'unique_users': 29628}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': 8759, 'unique_users': 7537}}} | {'diff_design': {'jio': {'total_sessions': -11182.0, 'unique_users': -9702.0}, 'nokia': {'total_sessions': -2986.0, 'unique_users': -2522.0}}} |

Comment: If I have multiple columns like `cell`, how can we handle such case?

Comment: Do it in a loop, and pass different column names as a parameter